# How to the ranks of first sample from ranked data

Tags: r, sorting, rank

I have two samples x and y and I am trying to compare them with a rank sum test. For the test statistics, I am trying to get sum of the ranks of the first sample with the following.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(2,4,5,7)

rank(sort(c(x,y)))
[1]  1.0 2.5 2.5 4.0 5.5 5.5 7.0 8.0
```

However, I don't know how to draw the ranks of the values of the first sample from that. Here's what I've tried

```
rank(sort(c(x,y)))[x]
[1] 1.0 2.5 2.5 4.0
```

but it returns the wrong answer, the right should be

```
 1.0 2.5 4.0 5.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to `sort` the concatenated `x` and `y` vector. The result of `rank(c(x, y))` gives you the ranks of `x` then the ranks of `y`, so to get the ranks of `x` you can do:

```r
rank(c(x, y))[seq_along(x)]
#> [1] 1.0 2.5 4.0 5.5
```

and to get the ranks of `y`, it's:

```r
rank(c(y, x))[seq_along(y)]
#> [1] 2.5 5.5 7.0 8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We may also use `head` on the `length` of 'x'

```
head(rank(c(x, y)), length(x))
[1] 1.0 2.5 4.0 5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it might be safer to put the samples into a data frame, which you can easily achieve with `stack()`.

```
(dat <- stack(list(x=x, y=y)))
#   values ind
# 1      1   x
# 2      2   x
# 3      3   x
# 4      4   x
# 5      2   y
# 6      4   y
# 7      5   y
# 8      7   y
```

Then you can do the subset explicitly by `"x"` and `"y"` which you obviously had in mind.

```
with(dat, rank(values)[ind == 'x'])
# [1] 1.0 2.5 4.0 5.5

with(dat, rank(values)[ind == 'y'])
# [1] 2.5 5.5 7.0 8.0
```